# Python - check subprocess activity every n seconds

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to make python script (currently on windows) which will open some sub-processes (which will run infinitely) and script should periodically check do all of opened sub-processes still work correctly. So it should be done with while loop, I guess.

The sub-processes are about FFMPEG livestreaming.

The problem is when I do `time.sleep(n)` in my loop, because then every FFMPEG livestream stops, so I suppose `time.sleep` affect on all of child subprocesses.

I have no idea how to make it work.

Here is my python code:

```
import os, time, sys, datetime, smtplib, configparser, logging, subprocess, psutil
import subprocess

def forwardudpstream(channel_number, ip_input, ip_output):
    try:
        ffmpeg_command = 'ffmpeg -i udp://' + ip_input + ' -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts "udp://' + ip_output + '?pkt_size=1316"'
        ffmpeg_output = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)
        return str(ffmpeg_output.pid)
    except:
        print ("Exception!")
        return '0'

while True:
    configuration = 'config.ini'
    channel_list_file = 'CHANNEL_LIST.conf'
    pid_folder = "D:\\Forward_UDP_Stream\\pids\\"
    channel_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(channel_list_file)]
    for line in channel_list:
        if not line.startswith('#') and ('|' in line):
            channel_number, ip_input, ip_output = line.split('|')
            print('----------')
            print("Channel number = ", channel_number)
            print("IP Input = ", ip_input)
            print("IP Output = ", ip_output)
            pid_file_found = False
            print("Checking if pid file exists...")
            for pidfile in os.listdir(pid_folder):
                if pidfile.startswith(channel_number + '-'):
                    print("Pid file is found for this channel.")
                    pid_file_found = True
                    pid = int(pidfile.split('-')[1].split('.')[0])
                    print("PID = ", str(pid))
                    print("Checking if corresponding process is active...")
                    if not psutil.pid_exists(pid):
                        print("Process is not active.")
                        print("Removing old pid file.")
                        os.remove(pid_folder + pidfile)
                        print("Starting a new process...")
                        pid_filename = channel_number + '-' + forwardudpstream(channel_number, ip_input, ip_output) + '.pid'
                        pid_file = open(pid_folder + pid_filename, "a")
                        pid_file.write("Process is running.")
                        pid_file.close()
                    else:
                        print("Process is active!")
                    break
            if pid_file_found == False:
                print("Pid file is not found. Starting a new process and creating pid file...")
                pid_filename = channel_number + '-' + forwardudpstream(channel_number, ip_input, ip_output) + '.pid'
                pid_file = open(pid_folder + pid_filename, "a")
                pid_file.write("Process is running.")
                pid_file.close()
            time.sleep(10)
```

Here is my **CHANNEL_LIST.conf** file example:

```
1|239.1.1.1:10000|239.1.1.2:10000
2|239.1.1.3:10000|239.1.1.4:10000
```

Perhaps there is some other solution to put waiting and sub-processes to work together. Does anyone have an idea?

**UPDATE:**
I finally make it work when I removed  `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` part from the subprocess command. 
Now it looks like this:

`ffmpeg_output = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)`

So now I'm confused why previous command was making a problem...?
Any explanation?

Comment: There is something very screwy with your code - _subprocess.Popen_ with _shell=False_ requires list of strings to run.It should not have worked at all. Besides - you leave your process objects un-referenced, meaning that after return from _forwardudpstream_ they are open to garbage collection

Comment: Since I'm going to use only hardcoded ffmpeg commands in _subprocess.Popen_, I guess then there is no problem to use _shell=True_ without list of strings? However, it actually works in both ways, at least on Windows..   
Regarding un-referenced objects, as you can see I'm just returning PID for a new child process that has been opened. PID number is then used to create coresponding file which will be used for periodical subprocess activity check, so returned PID number can be freely removed by garbage collector? Please correct me if I missed somethig...